# Alotting values using typedef struct

Tags: c, structure, typedef

I'm having some issues using writing code using the type def statments in unison with the member access operator. I want to allot the value, see below, the my structure defined variables. But each time I give it a try I go further down the spiral and confuse myself. What am I doing wrong? Why won't this program print the different values?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void outputDate(courseInfo course);

typedef struct{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
}date;

typedef struct{
    double avrage;
    int students;
    date start;
    date end;

}courseInfo;

int main(void){

    courseInfo course;
    course.avrage = 10;
    course.students=200
    course.start={17,17,17};
    course.end={16,16,16};


    outputDate();

    return 0;
}

void outputDate(courseInfo course){
    printf("avrage%d\n", course.avrage);
    printf("students%d\n", course.students);
    printf("start%d\n", course.start);
    printf("end%d\n", course.end);
    return;
}
```

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/t2AXBn)

Answer (score 2):

`start` is a structure, not an `int`, so using `%d` for the format code won't work.
Use something like
`printf("start %d %d %d\n", course.start.day, course.start.month, course.start.year);`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the printf problem, you should pass the course variable to the outputDate() function in main.

```
outputDate(course);
```